# MIPS instructions - addiu $sp, $sp, -4

Tags: mips

I am reading a code, as below, I am new in MIPS :

```
        .text
 main :
        addiu $sp, $sp, -4
```

Why addiu $sp, $sp, -4 is used?

Comment: it's adjusting the stack pointer for a new variable

Comment: [Dilemma related to function call's increment of SP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31390228/995714), [Stacks in MIPS. What is the purpose of 4 in addi $sp,$sp,-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202736/995714)